# Listening for a change in the foreground task

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to mobile development so please cut me some slack if I am missing something obvious.

Currently I am seeking a way to monitor a foreground task on iOS and Android. For example I want my program to do the following:

(Assuming my app is running in the background),

App "x" enters the foreground => Start timer in my app

App "x" leaves the foreground (either enters background or terminates) => Stop timer.

I have already looked through many cordova plugins but could only find code that monitored system notifications. I am looking for a way to listen for a change in the foreground application in the ***least cpu intensive way***.

I also understand that iOS has this feature built in. For example, it is possible to see "Screen time" for each application over the past 24 hours or the past 7 days. I'm not familiar with native code for either iOS or Android but I am not opposed to learning.

My question is, how can I listen to changes in this "foreground process" given my current set up of ionic/cordova?

If you need any more information about what I am using or if I have forgot something crucial please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are lifecycle events in cordova that you can use in that kind of needs. `deviceready`, `pause` and `resume` events. `pause` is fired when your app is moving to the background, `resume` when app is moving to the foreground. You add listeners to this events. In case of events activation, you can read current time (by for example JavaScript `Date` object) and then compare it to each other. For more info look at: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html